# How to insert a table into a cell in poi word?

Tags: apache-poi

I want to insert a table into a cell,I did a demo but failure, can anyone give some advice?

```
    XWPFDocument document = new XWPFDocument();
    XWPFTable tableTwo = document.createTable(1,1);
    XWPFTableRow tableTwoRow1 = tableTwo.getRow(0);
    tableTwoRow1.getCell(0).setText("aaaaaaaaaa");
    XWPFTable tableOne = document.createTable(2,2);
    XWPFTableRow tableOneRow1 = tableOne.getRow(0);
    XWPFTableRow tableOneRow2 = tableOne.getRow(1);
    tableOneRow1.getCell(0).setText("Test");
    tableOneRow1.getCell(1).setText("Test");
    tableOneRow2.getCell(0).setText("Test");
    tableOneRow2.getCell(1).insertTable(0, tableTwo);
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("D:\\2.docx");
    document.write(fos);
    fos.close();
```

Comment: What means `but failure`? Any exception or what?

Comment: there is no exception, but the tableTwo not inserted into the tableOne, tableTwo append beside tableOne.

Comment: Can you please create a [mcve]?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `XWPFTable` created using `XWPFDocument.createTable` will always belongs to the document. So it cannot later be taken from the document and putted into a cell.

For doing this, [XWPFTableCell.insertNewTbl](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/xwpf/usermodel/XWPFTableCell.html#insertNewTbl(org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlCursor)) is needed.

The following code works using actual `apache poi` versions:

```
import java.io.*;

import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.*;

public class CreateWordTableInTable {

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    XWPFDocument document = new XWPFDocument();

    XWPFTable tableOne = document.createTable(2,2);
    XWPFTableRow tablerow = tableOne.getRow(0);
    tablerow.getCell(0).setText("Test");
    tablerow.getCell(1).setText("Test");

    tablerow = tableOne.getRow(1);
    tablerow.getCell(0).setText("Test");

    XWPFParagraph paragraph = tablerow.getCell(1).getParagraphArray(0);
    XWPFTable tableTwo = tablerow.getCell(1).insertNewTbl(paragraph.getCTP().newCursor());

    tableTwo.getCTTbl().addNewTblPr().addNewTblBorders().addNewLeft().setVal(
     org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.STBorder.SINGLE);
    tableTwo.getCTTbl().getTblPr().getTblBorders().addNewRight().setVal(
     org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.STBorder.SINGLE);
    tableTwo.getCTTbl().getTblPr().getTblBorders().addNewTop().setVal(
     org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.STBorder.SINGLE);
    tableTwo.getCTTbl().getTblPr().getTblBorders().addNewBottom().setVal(
     org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.STBorder.SINGLE);
    tableTwo.getCTTbl().getTblPr().getTblBorders().addNewInsideH().setVal(
     org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.STBorder.SINGLE);
    tableTwo.getCTTbl().getTblPr().getTblBorders().addNewInsideV().setVal(
     org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.STBorder.SINGLE);

    tablerow = tableTwo.createRow();
    tablerow.createCell().setText("aaaaaaaaaa");
    tablerow.createCell().setText("jjjjjjjj"); 
    tablerow = tableTwo.createRow(); 
    tablerow.getCell(0).setText("bbbbbbbbbb"); 
    tablerow.getCell(1).setText("gggggggggg");

    document.write(new FileOutputStream("CreateWordTableInTable.docx"));
    document.close();

 }
}
```

But I would strongly recommend not to use this approach but to use merged cells instead. Tables which are contained in table cells are ugly. This is true for `HTML` as well as for `Word` as well as for all other text document formats which can contain tables.

Comment: You are right, `XWPFTableCell.insertNewTable()` was my own method, not one in POI.

Comment: I have tested your code, tableTwo  really can insert successfully.  But I want to know why tableTwo has no border?

Comment: The `tableTwo` has no border because `apache poi` does not set it automatically using `insertNewTbl`. So you must set it manually if needed. I will update my code to show how. But as said using merged cells within **one** table instead of nested table would be the better approach.

Comment: `tablerow = tableTwo.createRow();
      tablerow.createCell().setText("aaaaaaaaaa");
      tablerow.createCell().setText("jjjjjjjj");
      tablerow = tableTwo.createRow();
      tablerow.createCell().setText("bbbbbbbbbb");
      tablerow.createCell().setText("gggggggggg");` If I change tableTwo 1 row and 1 column to 2 row 2 column there is something wrong with the result: tableTwo have 7 cells!  you can tested it, and I want to know what the reasons of this bug? Thanks!

Comment: In a `Word` table each newly created row has as much cells as the row above it which was already present. So if you are creating new rows, there are cells already and each new created cell will be an additional one. So after creating a new row, you must **getting** the cells and not creating new ones if you don't want creating new ones. See my updated code.

Comment: @AxelRichter - How can I set the breadth of the cells of the tableTwo toa fixed value ? The cells are so narrow that the values are not fitting to a cell.

Answer (score 0):

To add a table into a cell, one can use XWPFTableCell's method:

```
public XWPFTable insertNewTbl(XmlCursor cursor)
```

so

```
XWPFTable table = cell.insertNewTbl(cell.getParagraphArray(cell.getParagraphs().size() - 1));
```

If u want to add the inner table into a paragraph that is not the first paragraph of a cell, you have to add a paragraph to the cell (obviously). In the newer versions of POI (tested on 5.2.3) you can just use the addParagraph() method of XWPFTableCell, but keep in mind that this method is flawed on some prior versions. For example this method on 5.2.3 updates the list of IBodyElements in the document:

```
public void addParagraph(XWPFParagraph p) {
    this.paragraphs.add(p);
    this.bodyElements.add(p);
}
```

but in the prior versions (4.1.2)

```
public void addParagraph(XWPFParagraph p) {
    this.paragraphs.add(p);
}
```

so, you have to use the XMLCursor for adding a paragraph, because the insertNewParagraph method updates the IBodyElemets list:

```
void addParagraphToCellUsingCursor(XWPFTableCell cell) {
    XmlCursor cursor = getCursorAfterParagraph(cell.getParagraphArray(cell.getParagraphs().size() - 1));
    XWPFParagraph cellParagraph = cell.insertNewParagraph(cursor);
}

public static XmlCursor getCursorAfterParagraph(XWPFParagraph previous) {
    XmlCursor cursor = previous.getCTP().newCursor();
    cursor.toEndToken();
    cursor.toNextToken();
    return cursor;
}
```