# How to solve Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 6, Size: 1 with apache poi table creation?

Tags: java, ms-word, format, apache-poi

I am creating a table within a table cell. The table cell +has many paragraphs. Few paragraphs have text and the table will be created at a certain paragraph. The code I have written is as follows. I debugged the code and I have seen that the *index 6* is present and all the values exists. There is no Null value anywhere.

```
XWPFTableRow mainTableRowThree = tableitem.getRow(2);
mainTableRowThree.getCell(0).removeParagraph(0);
XWPFParagraph p000 = mainTableRowThree.getCell(0).addParagraph();
XWPFRun run20=p000.createRun();
run20.setText("Beschreibung:");

XWPFRun run21=p000.createRun();
run21.setText(item.getDescription());

XWPFParagraph p001 = mainTableRowThree.getCell(0).addParagraph();
XWPFRun run22=p001.createRun();
run22.setText("Ansprechpartner:");
    
XWPFRun run23=p001.createRun();
run23.setText(item.getperson());

XWPFParagraph p002 = mainTableRowThree.getCell(0).addParagraph();
XWPFRun run24=p002.createRun();
run24.setText("Lösung:");

XWPFRun run25=p002.createRun();
run25.setText(item.getSolution());

.........
.........//Similarly for Paragraph p003,p004

XWPFParagraph p005 = mainTableRowThree.getCell(0).addParagraph();
XWPFRun run32=p005.createRun();
run32.setText("Produkte:"); //Below this the innertable has to be created

XWPFParagraph p0001 = mainTableRowThree.getCell(0).addParagraph(); //created a new paragraph for the nested table
generateNestedtable(item.getProducts(),document,p0001,mainTableRowThree); // A seperate method for the nested table creation

private void generateNestedtable(String towrite,XWPFDocument document,XWPFParagraph paragraph,XWPFTableRow tablerow)
  throws XmlException { 
  
  XWPFTable tableTwo = tablerow.getCell(0).insertNewTbl(paragraph.getCTP().newCursor()); //In this line there is the exception
  //The paragraph object here is not null and that I have already debugged.
  
     tableTwo.getCTTbl().addNewTblPr().addNewTblBorders().addNewLeft().setVal(
    org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.STBorder.SINGLE);
tableTwo.getCTTbl().getTblPr().getTblBorders().addNewRight().setVal(
    org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.STBorder.SINGLE);
tableTwo.getCTTbl().getTblPr().getTblBorders().addNewTop().setVal(
    org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.STBorder.SINGLE);
tableTwo.getCTTbl().getTblPr().getTblBorders().addNewBottom().setVal(
    org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.STBorder.SINGLE);
tableTwo.getCTTbl().getTblPr().getTblBorders().addNewInsideH().setVal(
    org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.STBorder.SINGLE);
tableTwo.getCTTbl().getTblPr().getTblBorders().addNewInsideV().setVal(
    org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.STBorder.SINGLE);
  }
```

I believe that the exception is due to `*insertNewTble(paragraph.getCTP().newCursor())*`. Is it because that after so many paragraphs before this table creation, the nested table is not created due to space constraints?

The stack trace is as follows

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 6, Size: 1
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheckForAdd(ArrayList.java:756)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.add(ArrayList.java:481)
    at org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFTableCell.insertNewTbl(XWPFTableCell.java:328)
```

Comment: Please share the complete stacktrace

Comment: The stack trace has been provided above.

Comment: Just to confirm: Are you saying the complete stack trace is only 4 lines long?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not able to reproduce the issue. The provided code is incomplete. Also the provided stack trace is incomplete. But the code line `at org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFTableCell.insertNewTbl(XWPFTableCell.java:328)` would must point to a `ArrayList.add` statement. That is true for [Apache POI 4.0.0](https://svn.apache.org/viewvc/poi/tags/REL_4_0_0_FINAL/src/ooxml/java/org/apache/poi/xwpf/usermodel/XWPFTableCell.java?view=markup#l328). And this is not the current Apache POI version.

Following **complete** example works for me using **current** Apache POI version 5.2.3:

```
import java.io.*;

import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.*;

public class CreateWordTableInTable1 {
    
 static void setAllBorders(XWPFTable table, XWPFTable.XWPFBorderType borderType, int size, int space, java.lang.String rgbColor) {
   table.setTopBorder(borderType, size, space, rgbColor);
   table.setRightBorder(borderType, size, space, rgbColor);
   table.setBottomBorder(borderType, size, space, rgbColor);
   table.setLeftBorder(borderType, size, space, rgbColor);
   table.setInsideHBorder(borderType, size, space, rgbColor);
   table.setInsideVBorder(borderType, size, space, rgbColor);    
 }

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    XWPFDocument document = new XWPFDocument();

    XWPFTable tableOne = document.createTable(2,2);
    
    tableOne.setWidth("100%");
    
    XWPFTableRow tablerow = tableOne.getRow(0);
    
    tablerow.getCell(0).setWidth("40%");
    tablerow.getCell(1).setWidth("60%");
    
    tablerow.getCell(0).setText("Test");
    tablerow.getCell(1).setText("Test");

    tablerow = tableOne.getRow(1);
    tablerow.getCell(0).setText("Test");

    //XWPFParagraph paragraph = tablerow.getCell(1).getParagraphArray(0);
    
    XWPFParagraph paragraph;
    XWPFRun run;
    
    //first paragraph is already present in table cell
    paragraph = tablerow.getCell(1).getParagraphArray(0);
    run = paragraph.createRun();
    run.setText("Paragraph 0");
   
    //create some more paragraphs in table cell
    for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
     paragraph = tablerow.getCell(1).addParagraph();
     run = paragraph.createRun();
     run.setText("Paragraph " + i);
    }
    
    paragraph = tablerow.getCell(1).addParagraph();
    run = paragraph.createRun();
    run.setText("Produkte:"); //below this the inner table has to be created

    //need an empty paragraph to start the table
    paragraph = tablerow.getCell(1).addParagraph();
    XWPFTable tableTwo = tablerow.getCell(1).insertNewTbl(paragraph.getCTP().newCursor());

    tableTwo.setWidth(0); // This is necessary because a XWPFTable created by insertNewTbl seems not to have full internally structure. It lacks the cell width field in this case.
    tableTwo.setWidth("100%");
    
    setAllBorders(tableTwo, XWPFTable.XWPFBorderType.SINGLE, 4, 0, "000000");
    
    tablerow = tableTwo.createRow();
    tablerow.createCell().setText("aaaaaaaaaa");
    tablerow.createCell().setText("jjjjjjjj"); 
    tablerow = tableTwo.createRow(); 
    tablerow.getCell(0).setText("bbbbbbbbbb"); 
    tablerow.getCell(1).setText("gggggggggg");

    try (FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("./CreateWordTableInTable.docx")) {
     document.write(out);
    }
    document.close();

 }
}
```

Maybe your problem is with the `XmlCursor`. Using your code it points to the begin of the paragraph containing the text "Produkte:". But it should point to a position after that text, shouldn't it? Microsoft Word itself will always use a own empty paragraph to start the table after.

My code produces:

[image]

---

Just tested. It is a bug in Apache POI version 4. And it is because `XWPFTableCell.addParagraph` adds a paragraph to the table cell but lacks adding that paragraph to the `ArrayList` `bodyElements`. So while trying to add the new table to the  `ArrayList` `bodyElements` (`bodyElements.add(i, newT);` in codeline 328 in XWPFTableCell.java) it fails since the `ArrayList` `bodyElements` lacks all the paragraphs added using `XWPFTableCell.addParagraph`.

This bug was fixed in Apache POI version 5.

Solution: **Always** use current Apache POI version. **Never** use old Apache POI versions.

Comment: What an excellent analysis @Axel! Hats off! Thanks a lot!